# Java Generics - Bound mismatch: The type Object is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable<E>>

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make a generic binary tree and and the nodes of the binary tree will be made of objects. In order to insert and move around the binary tree I am using the Comparable interface but the problem is that I cannot create a Binary Tree Object and make the Generics of type "Object".

The binary tree:

```
public class BinTreeGen<E extends Comparable<E>> implements BinTreeGenInterface<E> {
    private BinNodeGen<E> root = null;

    BinTreeGen() {
        root = null;
    }

    BinTreeGen(BinNodeGen<E> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }
}
```

The main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinTreeGen<Object> btg = new BinTreeGen<>(); //Bound mismatch: The type Object is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable<E>> of the type
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to solve this problem? Should I create a Binary Tree without the Comparable but how do I move around the binary tree then or what is the correct way to create the BinaryTreeGen Object?

Comment: What specific kind of objects do you want to store in `btg`? You can't store generic `Object`s as `Object` doesn't implement `Comparable`, but it'll work if you pick something more specific like `String` or `Integer`.

Comment: I created a class Person which stores the name and age of the person and I wanted to use that one in the binarytree. Without Comparable its possible to create the BinaryTreeGen but I dont know how to move around the BinaryTree then

Comment: Make that `BinTreeGen<Person> btg` then.

Comment: Same error... But I believe I found my mistake. I dont want to make the Binary Tree of type Person but the nodes. So this should work then. But thanks for taking your time

Comment: In general, you *do* want to make the binary tree type the same as its node type; you *don't* want to max 'n' match types

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem you're stuck with is this:

A binary tree requires an oracle. This oracle has the following function: Given any 2 objects that either exist in the tree or which are in the process of being added to the tree, **which one is before the other one**? Which one is 'lower'?

Without this oracle, you cannot make a binary tree.

Imagine I asked you to lay out a bunch of marbles in a binary tree. I hand you marbles and you're supposed to do this by weighing the marbles. However, you don't have an accurate scale and the difference in weight between any 2 marbles is real, but minute.

You **cannot** do the job asked of you. It is impossible.

The same applies here: The code of `BinTreeGen` has absolutely no idea how it could possibly 'weigh' an object. It has no idea how to either derive a property from any given object that is itself 'ordered' (such as a single number), or how, given 2 objects, to determine which one is 'lower'.

The point of that `E extends Comparable<E>` is that the thing you want to store in your binary tree is guaranteed to be 'self ordered': To be objects of a type that is guaranteed to let you invoke `a.compareTo(b)`, where `a` and `b` are **any** objects stored in the tree, and this method both exists and gives sane answers: A negative number if 'a' is lower, a positive number if 'b' is lower, and 0 if a and b are in fact the same object.

The fix, then, is to use something instead of `Object` (in `BinTreeGen<Object>`) which is **inherently** ordered. As defined by: it implements `Comparable<X>` where X is itself.

Some examples are:

- `java.lang.Integer`
- `java.lang.String`
- `java.lang.BigDecimal`

Without this, asking 'how do I make this work' is a bit like asking: "How do I find the corner in a circle" or "How do I go faster than the speed of light" or "How do I make 1+1 equal 3". You are asking for the impossible.